# Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

Tags: magento2, mageplaza

I used Mageplaza's Blog extension.  There's no problem locally, but when editing blog content online, it says "require is not defined"

[image]

Show /hide Editor button Click invalid

Comment: magento version?

Comment: magento version is 2.4.2

Comment: @Bob ever figured this one out? I'm having the same issue where it works on a dev enviorment, but not live.. :/

Answer (score 0):

Mageplaza's Blog is using old wysiwyg editor's js Tinymce 3. While in your magento version it's  Tinymce 4.

so,it's missing library of wysiwyg. so, you need to change code or simply you can disable wysiwyg from your field from block file.

Comment: It works in my local environment, just not online